# Code::Blocks - Cannot build multifile project without closing it first

Tags: c++, codeblocks

C++ newbie here. I've been trying to build a simple multifile project with a main.cpp source file and a single class separated into a source and a header file, with nothing inside the class but an empty constructor function, and no references in main.cpp to the class either. Basically all I do is create a console application and then add to it a class with the help of the template that comes with C::B, with the only change from the default settings being that I don't include a destructor in the class. So the end result is something like this:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

//---------------------
// someclass.h

#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

class someclass
{
    public:
        someclass();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // SOMECLASS_H

//---------------------
// someclass.cpp

#include "someclass.h"

someclass::someclass()
{
    //ctor
}
```

Compiling main.cpp and the header file works fine, but compiling someclass.cpp or building the project returns the following error:

> g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -I -c *path to the source file in question*
>   -o obj/Debug/someclass.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In
>   function _start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to main'

On the other hand, if I close the project, reopen it and try building it again, it works fine, and this appears to happen whenever new classes are introduced into a project. I would assume the code is missing something, but another machine running C::B doesn't seem to share this problem.

Comment: Are both main.cpp and someclass.cpp being compiled? It seems that only someclass.cpp is being compiled.

Comment: I am making a wild guess here that it's not regenerating the makefile (or whatever it is using internally), or not doing it correctly, and reopening forces it to do so. It could be a bug in the version you are using; I suggest comparing your version with the other one you say doesn't show the problem, and if there is a difference, try the working version.